# ANDROID - dx processing too slow

Tags: android, eclipse, dx

Is there a way in eclipse to pass parameter to dx (--no-optimize, etc) to improve speed of dx processing?

Answer (score 1):

create methods with less than 300 lines, divide the maximum you can, before I had created a method with 2000 lines and it took 10 minutes in Dx processing.